# Youtube API does not work with dynamically generated array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, youtube-api

I have this seemingly strange issue with Youtube API...
I am working on a script that will detect all youtube videos on a page and then replace them using Youtube API. This way I will be able to detect API events such as when the video ends, to display a message. I am creating a new instance of youtube player object for every video on the page. All good so far.

I dynamically generate video containers and am saving the video container ID and video ID into an array of objects (below is my current code).

The strange thing is when I generate this array of objects dynamically (using array.push() ), Youtube API does not work.
If I explicitly declare this array of objects, the Youtube API works fine.

---

to make it more clear, this does not work with Youtube API (illustration example):

```
var playerInfoList = [];
foreach loop{
   playerInfoList.push( object );
}
```

Screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/a0f21db4fb60e921be5cc1d1d52f948f.png

---

This works:

```
var playerInfoList = [
    {containerID:'social_share_custom_0', videoID:'KSyHWMdH9gk'},
    {containerID:'social_share_custom_1', videoID:'b-u5LE6X6ME'}
];
```

Screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/39bce30e4ebfb21119d48bbaf818d491.png

---

I made a sample page to demonstrate this, here it is:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    $content = '
    <h3>This is a sample page to demonstrate the issue...</h3>
    Text before <br /><br />
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/KSyHWMdH9gk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    Text in between.
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/b-u5LE6X6ME?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br /><br />Text after.';

    $return_HTML  = '';

    // match any iframes
    $pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>|<embed.*</embed>~';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);


    // START Youtube Script
    $YT_scripts = '
            <script>
                /*
                ** Array of objects
                ** params containerID, videoID
                */
                var playerInfoList = []; ';

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

        $embedPattern = '%(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})[a-zA-Z0-9\< \>\"]%x';

        $res=false;
        $res = preg_match($embedPattern, $match, $embedOutput); 

        if( $res ){
            $YT_scripts .= '
            //new object
            var newItem = {containerID:"social_share_custom_'.$index.'", videoID:"'.$embedOutput[1].'"};

            //put it into array
            playerInfoList.push(newItem);';             

            $wrappedframe = '<div class="social_share_custom_video_container" id="social_share_custom_'.$index.'"></div>';
            $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
        }
    $index++;
    }

    $content .= $YT_scripts.'</script>';    
    $return_HTML .= $content;   

    echo $return_HTML;
?>

<script>
//Load Yotube API
var tag = document.createElement("script"); 
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; 
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

/*
// if we declare this explicitly, Youtube API works.
// if this array if generated DYNAMICALLY (if we comment this out), Youtube API does not work.
var playerInfoList = [
    {containerID:'social_share_custom_0', videoID:'KSyHWMdH9gk'},
    {containerID:'social_share_custom_1', videoID:'b-u5LE6X6ME'}
];
*/

console.log( 'Object array length: ' + playerInfoList.length );

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        if(typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined')
            return; 

        for(var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length;i++) {
            var player = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i]);
        }
    }

    function createPlayer(listItem){
        console.log( listItem.containerID + ' - ' + listItem.videoID );

        return new YT.Player(listItem.containerID, {
            height: '350',
            width: '480',
            videoId: listItem.videoID,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
                'onError' : onPlayerError
            }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event){
        // video is Ready
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        console.log(event);

        if(event.data == 0) {
            // video Ended
            // showEndVideoPrompt();
            console.log('Video Ended.');
        }
        else if (event.data === 1) {
            //video Started
        }
        else if (event.data === 2) {
            //video Stopped
        }           
    }

    function onPlayerError(event) {
        // video Error
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have spent almost two days trying different things and still have no idea why this is happening. I searched for similar issues here but didn't find any other question that has this specific issue with dynamically generated object array and Youtube API.

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need more info. 
Thanks to all of you who can give a helping hand :)

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for Javascript errors?

Comment: @levi yes, I have checked for errors but there are no errors on the code and no errors on the javascript console either. I'm using Chrome latest version.


I had a programmer friend checking this out too and the same problem appears to him too. 

It seems to me like it is either a bug, ot something I'm not gasping about Youtube API....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the Regular-expression you are using to extract the video ID. The last bit `[a-zA-Z0-9\< \>\"]` is corrupting the `videoID` by consuming the last character of the ID, instead of it being captured along with the rest. Removing it should fix the problem.

Comment: You are EXACTLY right that the real problem was the regular-expression. I just found out too that it "eats" the last character and came here to post it as an update, just to find you already posted it :)

Unfortunately I don't understand regular expressions at all, so I was using what I found on the web. Do you know how can we fix it so it doesn't "eat" the last character?

for reference of other readers, this was the BAD regular-expression:
`$embedPattern = '%(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})[a-zA-Z0-9\< \>\"]%x';`

Comment: just remove the last part, so you are left with: `'%(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})%x'`